# VGA not detected after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: ati

my desktop PC using ati radeon hd 4350, when i installed ubuntu 11.04 and running application for checking and install  propertary VGA driver (`jockey-gtk`) then my 11.04 screen resolution, activating desktop effect compiz,etc  works well.

but the problems comes after i upgraded ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 , i can't login to my account but works by using guest account. and my 11.10 not detecting  ati radeon hd 4350 although i reinstall then reactivated the propertary driver.

Thanks for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 1):

AMD Catalyst 11.10 is out by now. Maybe you should install it manually, because of this :

> AMD announced last evening, October 31st, the immediate availability
>   for download of the AMD Catalyst 11.10 video driver for Linux
>   platforms.
>
> The new AMD Catalyst 11.10 driver brings initial support for the
>   Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) operating system. It also brings
>   production support for the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.7 operating
>   system.
>
> A few improvements are also present in the new AMD Catalyst 11.10,
>   especially for the AMD Brazos platform, as well as lots of bugfixes,
>   such as a segmentation fault issue for the Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty
>   Narwhal) 64-bit edition and GNOME Shell corruption issues.

I Thing your problem will be fixed after a driver upgrade ;)

Here's 11.10 Driver for both x86 and x86_64 Linux Distros.

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had a similar problem on a HP Pavilion 1700N Desktop with an Nvidia 6150 LE. The following solved the problem for me:

1. Boot with option "nomodeset".
2. Install the vendor´s latest driver (http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/290.10/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-290.10.run in this case).